# What's the Entry Point for a URL Scheme in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, url-scheme, entry-point

I registered an URI scheme for my C# WPF GUI application by following the official guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa767914(v=vs.85)

When I click on a link it will open up my app or bring it in the foreground. But where do I get the URL the app was started with? The guide uses the main method. But my GUI app has no main method.

Whats the method I need to implement to get the clicked URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `App.xaml.cs`, override the [`OnStartup` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application.onstartup?view=netframework-4.7.2) or subscribe to the [`Application.Startup` event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application.startup?view=netframework-4.7.2). The `StartupEventArgs` has an [`Args` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.startupeventargs.args?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_StartupEventArgs_Args) which gives you your command-line arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the link you provided, you would use the `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` to get the `args` like in the example for your GUI only app.
Bear in mind that the first argument in that array is going to be the executable file name. For more information go to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getcommandlineargs?view=netframework-4.7.2)